# Is it possible to open a new tab on a particular line in vim?

Tags: vim

I have tried both of the following without success.

```
tabnew Foo.java +30
tabnew Foo.java:30
```

The first one gives an error message, while Vim opens interprets the whole string as a filename in the second case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reverse the arguments a bit, try this:

```
tabnew +30 Foo.java
```